# Un-/Check behavior in C# TreeView

Tags: c#, checkbox, treeview

I found a lot about treeview and checkboxes in treeviews...

but one thing seems to be undiscussed.

I have my treeview like

```
[x] Foo
 L [x] One
 L [x] Two
 L [x] Three
[x] Bar
 L [ ] One
 L [x] Two
 L [x] Three
[ ] Hello
 L [ ] One
 L [ ] Two
 L [ ] Three
```

Now when I check my parent checkbox e.g. `Foo` than all child get selected. Also they get deselected by unchecking `Foo`. To do this I have this Method

```
private void TreeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TreeNode childNode in e.Node.Nodes)
    {
        childNode.Checked = e.Node.Checked;
    }
}
```

I tried a lot with using `count` and others but could not achive what i'm trying to achive.

So what I want is, when I check `Two` in TreeNode `Hello` than `Hello` should get checked. Without checking `One` and `Three`. Check-/Unchecking `Hello` should select/deselect all childs.

Is this even possible?

Because when `Hello` gets checked, it fires the `TreeView1_AfterCheck`-event! What actually check/unchecks all childs.

And most of my tries ended up in an endless loop.

So my Question actually is:

Can I achive the above described behavior?

Ask me if something is unclear.

Comment: Is this autogenerated databound treeview or manually created?

Comment: manually created

Comment: Did some changes in the answere. Now it works perfect. Thanks to Rahul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a similar application where I had to do the same thing which you are trying to achieve. Its in VB.Net. Here's the snippet. If it did help, do accept this answer, comment further if you couldn't understand any part of it.

VB.NET :

```
Private isChildCheck As Boolean = False
Private Sub TREE_VIEW_AfterCheck(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs)
    If e.Action <> TreeViewAction.Unknown Then   ' The code only executes if the user caused the checked state to change.
        If e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0 Then
            If isChildCheck Then
                isChildCheck = False
                Exit Sub 'This will check the parent to exit AfterCheck loop
            End If
            ' Calls the CheckAllChildNodes method, passing in the current 
            ' checked value of the TreeNode whose checked state changed. 
            CheckAllChildNodes(e.Node, e.Node.Checked)
        Else
            e.Node.Parent.Checked = True
            isChildCheck = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub   'After a tree node's Checked property is changed, all its child nodes are updated to the same value.

Private Sub CheckAllChildNodes(treeNode As TreeNode, nodeChecked As Boolean)

    For Each node As TreeNode In treeNode.Nodes
        node.Checked = nodeChecked

        If node.Nodes.Count > 0 Then
            ' If the current node has child nodes, call the CheckAllChildsNodes method recursively.
            CheckAllChildNodes(node, nodeChecked)
        End If
    Next node
End Sub  'Checks the childnodes of a node recursively
```

C#.NET (*Edit by Dwza after clearing behavior changes for thoese who need it*)

```
private bool isChildCheck = false;
private void TREE_VIEW_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    // The code only executes if the user caused the checked state to change.
    if (e.Action != TreeViewAction.Unknown)
    {
        if (e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0)
        {
            if (isChildCheck)
            {
                isChildCheck = false;
                return;
               //This will check the parent to exit AfterCheck loop
            }
            // Calls the CheckAllChildNodes method, passing in the current 
            // checked value of the TreeNode whose checked state changed. 
            CheckAllChildNodes(e.Node, e.Node.Checked);
        }
        else
        {
            e.Node.Parent.Checked = GetCheckStateOfChildNodes(e.Node.Parent);
            isChildCheck = !e.Node.Parent.Checked;
        }
    }
}
//After a tree node's Checked property is changed, all its child nodes are updated to the same value.

private void CheckAllChildNodes(TreeNode treeNode, bool nodeChecked)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in treeNode.Nodes)
    {
        node.Checked = nodeChecked;
        if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
        {
            // If the current node has child nodes, call the CheckAllChildsNodes method recursively.
            CheckAllChildNodes(node, nodeChecked);
        }
    }
} //Checks the childnodes of a node recursively

//Additional Method to react on behavior when all childs are checked/unchecked
//This part was added by dwza and is not in the VB part
private bool GetCheckStateOfChildNodes(TreeNode treeNode)
{
    foreach(TreeNode node in treeNode.Nodes)
    {
        if (node.Checked)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Hope this conversion will help you.(Converted using CodeConverter)

Comment: truly its quit difficult to unerstand what you did there :D i'm not so famillier with vb. You created a function to check all childnodes and call this in the event. There you check if current node has childs and if not, you set the parent checked. On the outer part you define a boolean the act with it in the event... i had some similar and this ended up in a memory crash :D i'll try to translate this into c# and hola back :D

Comment: I've converted the code to c# for u. I've used a boolean variable which would be set True if the node is a single Child(without any subchild) when selected(in your case 'Two'), followed by setting its parent checkbox to True(In your case 'Hello', this will shoot after check event again) but this time as the boolean variable is true, it will exit the method and resetting the boolean to false

Comment: I had this done by the time as well. Works very well :) only case is, if i uncheck all childs, parent is still checked. But i guess i will get this running too :)

Comment: Yes, you would have to do something for the parent's check state. Happy to help :)

Comment: I made some edits in your post and now it works like a charm. Thanks a lot for your help. Finaly this question is solved for others who may seek for this behavior :)